# Custom Missing Template Handler in CF admin

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-2016

When I try to specify my custom error page as the Missing Template Handler in the CF admin settings, it gives me the below error.

```
The file specified as the site wide missing template handler does not exist. The default missing template handler will be used until a replacement is created.
```

This is the OS path of my file

```
C:\ColdFusion2016\cfusion\wwwroot\ErrorPages\404.cfm
```

Here is my web path

```
http://localhost:8500/ErrorPages/404.cfm
```

I tried with both path but it is given the same error, I checked and ensured that the file is exist in the path. Then why this error is showing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `Missing Template Handler` input field ***is asking for a relative path***.

> Specify the relative path to the template to execute when ColdFusion
>   cannot find a requested template.

In your case, `C:\ColdFusion2016\cfusion\wwwroot\ErrorPages\404.cfm` is an absolute path and it will not work.

Enter this: `/ErrorPages/404.cfm`, this one should work.